# redux-observable error: Uncaught TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm using react native, redux, and redux-observables(with rxjs5), and making an ajax request. the problem is I can't return actions when an error happens.

here is my code:

```js
//action creators
export const loginSucceeded = token => {
 return {
  type: Types.LOGIN_SUCCEEDED,
  payload: {
   token
  }
 };
};

export const login = (username, password) => {
 return {
  type: Types.LOGIN,
  pauload: {
   username,
   password
  }
 };
};

export const loginFailed = () => {
 return {
  type: Types.LOGIN_FAILED
 };
};


//epic
const authEpic = (action$, store$) =>
 action$.ofType(Types.LOGIN).mergeMap(action => {
  const authBody = {..};
  const headers = {..};
  return ajax
   .post(API.LOGIN, authBody, headers)
   .map(result => {
    return Actions.loginSucceeded(result.response.access_token);
   })
   .catch(err => {
    return Actions.loginFailed();
   });
 });
```

apparently, the problem is with this line:

`return Observable.of(Actions.loginFailed());`

if I change it to return each of these sentences, I still get the same error

```js
Observable.of(Actions.loginFailed);
Observable.of(Actions.loginFailed());
Actions.loginFailed;
Actions.loginFailed();
```

and here  is the error:

```html
index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:78220 Uncaught TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at Object.subscribeToResult (index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:78220)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (Button.js:88)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (index.js:19)
    at InnerSubscriber._error (Button.js:15)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.error (observable.js:13)
    at MapSubscriber._next (Rx.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (observable.js:5)
    at MapSubscriber._next (Rx.js:57)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (observable.js:5)
    at AjaxSubscriber.next (ReplaySubject.js:82)
```

and I read lots of StackOverflow questions about it, but almost all of them had the wrong functioncalls, and none applied to or worked on my problem.